# Google tag manager support for amp-pages?

Tags: html, google-tag-manager, amp-html

So I'm creating a base template for my CMS to generate AMP-HTML Pages. As of  Google & AMP Documentation it supports Google Analytics by including GA credentials in JSON in script tag and by including Google Analytics for AMP js file.

My concern is all of the tracking being done on my pages are through Google Tag manager, I'm not really finding a way to include Google Tag Manager credentials or scripts in my AMP-HTML Pages.

Comment: found a product forum regarding your concern. As of now Google Tag Manager can not be use in AMP pages. "One key of AMP, is performance, and allowing the runtime to optimize loading. Tag Manager adds a level of indirection, and complication. 
Adding the tag manager to a page, adds an arbitrary number of further dependencies." And Google Analytics tag is the workaround for GTM. Here is the [source](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/2hp84ziiZKQ) of the said features for AMP-HTML.

Answer (score 0):

GTM support for AMP launched today. You can find more details here: https://analytics.googleblog.com/2016/10/google-tag-manager-giving-mobile.html